# Parallel I/O - why does it work?

Tags: python, io, parallel-processing

I have a python function which reads a line from a text file and writes it to another text file. It repeats this for every line in the file. Essentially:

```
Read line 1 -> Write line 1 -> Read line 2 -> Write line 2...
```

And so on.

I can parallelise this process, using a queue to pass data, so it is more like:

```
Read line 1 -> Read line 2 -> Read line 3...

              Write line 1 -> Write line 2....
```

My question is - why does this work (as in why do I get a speed up?). Sounds like a daft question, but I was thinking - surely my hard disk can only do one thing at once? So why isn't one process put on hold til the other is completed?

Things like this are hidden from the user when writing in a high level language..I'd like to know whats going on at low level?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short: IO buffering. Two levels of it, even.

First, Python itself has IO buffers. So, when you write all those lines to the file, Python doesn't necessarily invoke the `write` syscall immediately - it does that when it flushes its buffers, which could be anytime from when you call write until you close the file. This clearly won't affect you if you write at such a level as you make the syscalls yourself.

But separate to this, the operating system will *also* implement buffers. These work the same way - you make the 'write to disk' syscall, the OS puts the data in its write buffer and will use that when other processes read that file back. But it doesn't necessarily write it to disk yet - it can wait, theoretically, until you unmount that filesystem (possibly at shutdown). This is (part of) why it can be a bad idea to unplug a USB storage device without unmounting or 'safely removing' it, for example - things you've written to it aren't necessarily *physically* on the device yet. Anything the OS does is unaffected by what language you're writing in, or how much of a wrapper around the syscalls you have.

As well as this, both Python and the OS can do read buffering - essentially, when you read one line from the file, Python/the OS anticipates that you might be interested in the next several lines as well, and so reads them into main memory to avoid having to defer all the way down to the disk itself later.

Comment: A good description, thanks. I wonder if there are techniques we can implement (in python) to control this, and whether having control over it would allow us to further improve performance or not?

Comment: @jramm from Python, `open` takes an optional `buffering` argument. 0 means to turn buffering off, 1 means the buffer is flushed every time you write a newline (line buffered), other positive integers are a buffer size in bytes; negative values use the default. The default changed between Python 2 and Python 3 - the Python 2 docs say it is "usually" either fully buffered (the buffer size is the file size) or line buffered depending on the type of file; in Python 3, it is line buffered for ttys, and a heuristic otherwise. The default is usually already quite tuned, which is why it's the default.

Comment: You can't AFAIK usually change the OS buffering policies, though. Or, rather, any tuning that they present is likely to be a privileged operation. But, again, the defaults are usually what they are because extensive testing has found them to be good for most common situations.